# Strtok use and finding the second element

Tags: c, strtok

I am writing a program that which that asks the user to input two words, separated by commas.  I also have to write  a function that finds the second word in the string and copies that word into a new memory location (without the comma).  The function should return a pointer to the new memory location.  Main should then print the original input string and the second word.

This is my code so far :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char*secondWordFinder(char *userInput)

int main ()

{

        char*userInput;
        char*result;

        userInput=malloc(sizeof(char)*101);

        printf("Please Enter Two Words Separated by a comma\n");
        fgets(userInput,101, stdin);

        printf("%s",userInput);

        result=secondWordFinder(userInput);
        printf("%s",result);

        free(userInput);

        return 0;
}

    char*secondWordFinder(char *userInput)

    {
        char*userEntry;
        char*ptr;
        int i;
        i=0;

        for(i=0; i<strlen(userInput);i++)
        {
            userEntry=strtok(userInput, ",");
            userEntry=strtok(NULL,",");
            pointer=strcpy(ptr,userEntry);
        }
        return ptr;
    }
```

I am not getting the a`enter code here actual output what am i doing wrong???

Comment: `ptr` is uninitialized, so trying to `strcpy` to it is an error (undefined behavior).

Comment: What aren't you getting? It isn't clear what "the a`enter code here actual output" means.  Can you clarify please?

Comment: You could use `sscanf()` for extracting the second word, which is more compact and reliable.

Comment: And stop using malloc() for function scope storage. It's simply `char userInput[101];`

Comment: my output currently is : xxx,yyy and then I get xxx,yyy but it will not print out the the second token which is what is what I have to print out along with the original input string which is xxx,yyy

Comment: you could take a look at `strchr()` instead, strtok seems like overkill here e.g. print second string `puts( strchr(userInput, ',') + 1 );` although you should check if there is a comma in the string first

Answer (score 0):

When extracting the second token, you say it must be followed by a comma.

```
userEntry = strtok(NULL, ",");
```

But it's actually followed by a newline. Try this:

```
userEntry = strtok(NULL, ",\n");
```

This works if the 2nd word is the last one, but also if it's followed by further comma separated words.

And yes, you can throw away the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Several issues:

```
    for(i=0; i<strlen(userInput);i++)
    {
        userEntry=strtok(userInput, ",");
        userEntry=strtok(NULL,",");
        pointer=strcpy(ptr,userEntry);
    }
```

- You're repeating these operations for *every character in the input string*, which doesn't make sense - this doesn't need to be in a loop at all;
- You haven't initialized `ptr` to point anywhere meaningful, so you're attempting to copy `userEntry` to some random chunk of memory;
- After the second call to `strtok`, `userEntry` already points to the second string - you can simply return `userEntry`

You should be able to rewrite this as

```
strtok(userInput, ", "); // accounts for any spaces between the comma and next string
userEntry = strtok( NULL, ", ");
return userEntry;
```

You will probably want to remove the trailing newline from the second word (if it exists) before returning it; one way to do that is

```
char *newline = strchr( userEntry, '\n' );
if ( newline )
  *newline = 0;
```

**EDIT**

If the requirement is that you have to copy the second word to a new buffer in `secondWordFinder` and return the pointer to the new buffer, then you'll have to do something along the lines of

```
ptr = malloc( strlen( userEntry ) + 1 );
if ( ptr )
  strcpy( ptr, userEntry );

return ptr;
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! It works now, however I had one question though, i have to copy the second token into a new memory location so for that will i have to malloc memory?